# Source Words & Huffman Codes

Tags: probability, information-theory, coding-theory

A source $S$ has source words $w_1, w_2, \ldots, w_n$, with probabilities $p_1 \geq p_2 \geq \ldots \geq p_n > 0$. Let $C$ be a binary Huffman code for $S$, and let $l$ be the length of the longest code word in $C$. Let $L(C)$ be the expected length of $C$.

Suppose you replace $w_n$ by two source words $w_a$ and $w_b$ with positive probabilities $p_a$ and $p_b$ respectively, where $p_a + p_b = p_n$. Call the new Huffman Code $C’$. What is $L(C’) – L(C)$?

So what I understand is that $L(C) = l_1p_1 + l_2p_2 + \ldots + l_np_n$ and $L(C’) = l_1p_1 + l_2p_2 + \ldots + (l_ap_a + l_bp_b)$
So if I were to find the difference $L(C’) – L(C)$ I am thinking that I would simply be left with $l_ap_a + l_bp_b - l_np_n$, but I have a feeling there is more to this than I presume.

Any ideas or suggestions would be greatly helpful!

Comment: Are you asking this question in the context of a proof of optimality of Huffman coding? Or do you have interest for some other reason?

Comment: It really isn’t clear just what you’re asking. For instance, you mention $\ell$, but nothing in the question seems to depend on it. Are you considering the case in which the leaf for $w_n$ becomes an internal vertex with daughter leaves for $w_a$ and $w_b$? In that case $\ell_a=\ell_b=\ell_n+1$, and $L(C')-L(C)=p_n$.

Comment: My professor posed this question as a possible midterm task and I'm simply trying to make sure that I am understanding the information correctly. A proof within the context of optimality may shed some light. However, I am unsure whether wa and wb are leaves for wn, I believe they are since the sum of their probabilities is the probability of wn. But the question that I'm technically asking is "what is L(C’) – L(C) considering the changes made on L(C)?"

Comment: @Mike: It’s what you wrote, $\ell_ap_a+\ell_bp_b-\ell_np_n$, but this doesn’t really say much without more context.

Answer (score 0):

One big assumption that you are making is that nothing else changes, which is not generally true. But in your case it is true. Consider the algorithm that calculates an optimal code for your problem.
If you run this algorithm for $S'$ at first step it merges the two lowest probabilities $p_a$ and $p_b$ and creates $p_n$. The rest of algorithm will run exactly like the source $S$.

One more observation that we should make is that the two new symbols will both have the same length (because they were merged together). and this length is exactly one more than $l_n$ (because algorithm runs the same way after that merge).

Now calculating what you already have:
$l_a \times p_a + l_b \times p_b - l_n \times p_n = l_a \times (p_a + p_b) - l_n \times p_n = l_a \times p_n - l_n \times p_n = (l_a - l_n) \times p_n = 1 \times p_n = p_n $